# Return total of features with ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to query an ArcGIS REST [API endpoint](https://gisapps.cm-lisboa.pt/arcgisapps/rest/services/GOPI_Maps_Secure/NaMinhaRuaRead_PROD/MapServer/0/query) and would like to get an added field with the count of features in the search. If I use `Return Count Only` as `true`, I will get the count, but not the features. I've also tried to add a count variable to `Output Statistics` but it replaces the rest of the query.

Comment: The features returned could be different than the features counted, but counting the returned features shouldn't cause data loss -- please [Edit] the Question to include your code.

Comment: I'm not using any code. I just want to use the endpoint to get the features + the count in a single json output.

Comment: Well, if you want to solve the problem in JavaScript or Python (or even Java), the task is pretty easy, but if you're looking for a code-free solution, you might be waiting a while.

Comment: Not sure I'm explaining myself correctly here. I'm talking about using the query (linked above) to produce a Json output that includes both a list of features (latest 1000) and a total of features in the database. So all I want to know is whether there is something I can use in that form that produces such an output.

Comment: Any client could easily reformat the object to include that, but since array length is a property of the array, it's considered redundant to need. `ReturnCountOnly` is very fast, and generally used to manage pagination.  Clogging up the object with all that data makes it less manageable.

Comment: I can't have pagination if I don't have the totals. `Array.length` won't do because I want to know how many features are left. Using `ReturnCountOnly` will require two API calls.

Comment: Yup, that's the way it works. Two REST calls to have both the total and the first page of data.